# CISCO: conditional port-based NAT (policy-based PAT)?

Tags: cisco, nat, pat

I have a problem to nat-translate inbound http packets to different local_ips based on some condition (like dscp bits set). Actually the dscp bits get set on the incoming trafic using NBAR. I hope NBAR happens BEFORE nat translation on the nat outside interface. If not maybe more sofisticated solution needed.

Here is what I need approximately:

```
nat inside source static tcp <internal_ip_1> 80 interface <outside_interface> 80 <if dscp bits = af13> 
nat inside source static tcp <internal_ip_2> 80 interface <outside_interface> 80 <if dscp bits = af12>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put a route-map on NAT.  What I'm not sure about is what conditions are valid to match upon in the route map to do conditional NAT (whether DSCP bits, etc are valid comparisons).

Check out the example below and see if you can give it a try relative to your objective.

https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/26021/how-configure-static-nat-route-maps